# Extracting the time information from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, posixct

I have a dataframe of timestmaps in R for which the dates are completely gibberish. I am looking to extract time information and substitute the correct date. But I am running into some issue. I have shown a part of the dataframe (Time_df)

```
Time_df = 
                  Time1               Time2      Time3      Time4      Time5
102 1970-01-01 07:00:00 1970-01-01 19:00:00 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 1970-01-01
103 1970-01-01 00:00:00 1970-01-02 00:00:00 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 1970-01-01
104 1970-01-01 00:00:00 1970-01-02 00:00:00 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 1970-01-01
105 1970-01-01 06:00:00 1970-01-01 22:00:00 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 1970-01-01
106 1970-01-01 08:00:00 1970-01-01 21:00:00 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 1970-01-01

dput(Time_df) =

 structure(list(Time1 = structure(c(43200, 18000, 18000, 39600, 
46800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Time2 = structure(c(86400, 
104400, 104400, 97200, 93600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Time3 = structure(c(18000, 18000, 18000, 18000, 18000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Time4 = structure(c(18000, 18000, 
    18000, 18000, 18000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Time5 = structure(c(18000, 18000, 18000, 18000, 18000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("Time1", "Time2", "Time3", 
"Time4", "Time5"), row.names = 102:106, class = "data.frame")
```

If I look at the structure it is all in POSIXct format

```
str(Time_df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Time1: POSIXct, format: "1970-01-01 07:00:00" "1970-01-01 00:00:00" "1970-01-01 00:00:00" ...
 $ Time2: POSIXct, format: "1970-01-01 19:00:00" "1970-01-02 00:00:00" "1970-01-02 00:00:00" ...
 $ Time3: POSIXct, format: "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" ...
 $ Time4: POSIXct, format: "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" ...
 $ Time5: POSIXct, format: "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" ...
```

But when I am trying to extract the time, it is giving me an error

```
times = strftime(Time_df, format="%H:%M:%S")
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

I can extract time for individual columns but not for the whole dataframe. I do have 42 columns, so I was hoping for a cleaner method. This is what I am going for:

```
Mon = rep("03/20/17", 6)
Tue = rep("03/21/17", 6)
Wed = rep("03/22/17", 6)
Thu = rep("03/23/17", 6)
Fri = rep("03/24/17", 6)
Sat = rep("03/25/17", 6)
Sun = rep("03/26/17", 6)

dates = c(Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun)
t = strftime(Time_df, format="%H:%M:%S")
x = paste(dates, t)
```

Comment: Would you please run and copy the output of `dput(Time_df)` so we can more easily help out? My guess is that the `anytime` library is going to be your friend on this one.

Comment: `Time_df_new = lapply(Time_df, function(x) strftime(x, format="%H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: This works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `apply` by column (2):

```
apply(Time_df,2,strftime, format="%H:%M:%S")

     Time1      Time2      Time3      Time4      Time5     
[1,] "07:00:00" "19:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"
[2,] "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"
[3,] "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"
[4,] "06:00:00" "22:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"
[5,] "08:00:00" "21:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"
```